# Why was Whistler in Sona?

Tags: plot-explanation, prison-break

In Season 3, Whistler was in prison and it was told that he could have killed the mayor's son, but it was hinted as being speculative. After watching Season 3 and the first part of Season 4, it is clear that Whistler is very smart and was working for the company. I imagine that he had better things to do than killing the mayor's son in Panama City? How did he come to Sona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Prison Break Wiki](http://prisonbreak.wikia.com/wiki/James_Whistler):

> Before Whistler was incarcerated in the **Sona Federal Penitentiary**, he allegedly was a fisherman, running a charter boat between America and Australia. One day, he got a call demanding to know exactly where he took a naturalist of some sort, who took water samples and measurements. He then worked for *Gretchen Morgan*. He said he couldn't remember – but then *government types started snooping around*. When James had a bar fight, he killed the Mayor's son, leading to his incarceration in **Sona**. The people who are trying to get him out demand that as soon as they do, he show them where he took that guy. After he was transferred into **Sona**, he hid into a crawlspace as most inmates wanted to turn him in to The Mayor for their freedom.

My guess is, whoever was following him around (*read The Company*), was behind him being sent to Sona. They framed him for the murder of the Mayor's son so that they could use his freedom as leverage to extract the information. I say "framed", because Whistler doesn't come across a guy who would kill somebody in a bar fight. Moreover, he repeatedly proclaims his innocence to numerous characters (*with a lot of conviction*).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't understand. Why should The Company frame him and then make a lot of effort to put Michael there and rescue him?

Comment: Whistler was not willing to give The Company what they were seeking. So they framed him, put him in there and asked him to turn over the info if he wanted to be rescued. Now, to make it a melting-pot for Whistler they created a situation where he was being hunted for by the Mayor. So he **had to get out**. This is where Scolfield comes into the picture.